# How to set icon for Toolbar when change Fragment in Android

Tags: android

I am developing an app with Sliding menu. In sliding menu,I have a category list. When user choose one category,fragment will be commited and toolbar will change title and icon of category. Setting title is simply but I dont know how to set icon for toolbar. So anyone help me please. Thank you

Comment: you can use interface for that

Comment: Thank you. But may you make more clearly?

Comment: first try your self and if not able to implement i will put my code

Comment: That's great,very simply with short code. You save my day.

Answer (score 1):

**For adding Home icon to toolbar,**

```
    //To enable home icon on toolbar
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //To change the icon
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
```

Comment: Thank you but fragment does not support getSupportActionBar method.

Comment: Using getActivity() method, we can get the obejct of activity.  ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar() ;

Comment: Problem solved. In my case,I use interface in every fragment to set icon in MainActivity.